# How to remove selected option from multiple dropdown on click a button in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have select dropdown whose option value comes from the array of object.When I click add button new dropdown will be added and on click delete button particular dropdown will be deleted.On page load select an option(need to onchange the dropdown) then click add button and you will get other dropdown below.Now here requirement is, selected options should not be repeated again into added dropdown after adding a new dropdown. Till now working fine.The problem is all dropdown is getting updated.Here is the code below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxfanw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

### app.component.html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
           
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
        <tr>
            <td>
               <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
                <option *ngFor="let title of arraydata" [value]="title.name" >{{title.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="addFieldValue()">Add</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let field of fieldArray; let i = index">
            <td>
                <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
                
                <option *ngFor="let title of arraydata" [value]="title.name" >{{title.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
          
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default"  type="button" (click)="deleteFieldValue(i)">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
fieldArray: Array<any> = [];
 newAttribute: any = {};
arraydata = [{"name":"name1","value":1},{"name":"name2","value":2},{"name":"name3","value":3},{"name":"name4","value":4}]
selectedDevice:any;
    
    
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.arraydata)
     
  }
  onChange(deviceValue) {
    this.selectedDevice = deviceValue;
}

    addFieldValue() {
        const index = this.arraydata.findIndex(x => x.name ===this.selectedDevice);
        console.log(index);
        this.arraydata.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(this.arraydata);
        this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
        this.newAttribute = {};
    }

    deleteFieldValue(index) {
        this.fieldArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i've worked on your code and here is how i make it work

first you have to change arraydata  to an array of arrays

```
 i = 0;
 arraydata = [
  [
   { name: "name1", value: 1 },
   { name: "name2", value: 2 },
   { name: "name3", value: 3 },
   { name: "name4", value: 4 }
 ]
];
```

and here is the add dropdown method

```
addFieldValue() {
   const arr = [...this.arraydata];
   this.arraydata.push(
    arr[this.i].filter(x => x.name !== this.selectedDevice)
   );
   this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute);
   this.newAttribute = {};
   this.i += 1;
}
```

and your html becomes

```
<tr>
 <td>
    <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let title of arraydata[0]" [value]="title.name" >{{title.name}}</option>
    </select>
 </td>

 <td>
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="addFieldValue()">Add</button>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let field of fieldArray; let i = index">
  <td>
    <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
     <option *ngFor="let title of arraydata[i+1]" [value]="title.name" >{{title.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </td>

  <td>
    <button class="btn btn-default"  type="button" (click)="deleteFieldValue(i)">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

here is the working code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujyrdr?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually we cannot change the array to array of array here because this will be coming from backend in our project. Is there any way without changing it